# print rearranged dataframe to screen with loops or `purrr::map()`

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse, purrr

I have data in a form like this (reproducible code below):

```
#>   y x char
#> 1 1 1    a
#> 2 1 2    b
#> 3 1 3    c
#> 4 2 1    d
#> 5 2 2    e
#> 6 2 3    f
#> 7 3 1    g
#> 8 3 2    h
#> 9 3 3    i
```

```
df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
           y = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
           x = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
        char = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i")
)
df
```

Is there an easy way to print to the screen using `y` values as the y axis, and `x` values as the x axis and the third column (`char`) as the values? A solution with `map()` would be great.

So my desired output would look like

```
   abc
   def
   ghi
```

I started trying to loop through y and x, with a view to using `purrr::map()`, but I haven't gotten very far.

```
if (df$y==1 & df$x==1){
print(df$char)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `tidyr::spread()` is for:

```r
spread(df, x, char)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert your data.frame into a `matrix`:

```
a <- matrix(
  data = df$char, 
  nrow = length(unique(df$x)), 
  ncol = length(unique(df$y)),
  "dimnames" = list(unique(df$y), unique(df$x)),
  byrow = TRUE
)
```

it will be:

```
  1   2   3  
1 "a" "b" "c"
2 "d" "e" "f"
3 "g" "h" "i"
```

To concatenate the strings into a column as you wish:

```
for (r in 1:nrow(a)) {
   print(paste(a[r, ], collapse = ''))
}

[1] "abc"
[1] "def"
[1] "ghi"
```